# Unable to install robot-framework-ride with python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I need to install robot framework.

i had installed python 3.7, wxPython and robotframework. Need to install robotframework-ride. While trying `pip install robotframework-ride`, getting error `pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mani~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ee73re19\robotframework-ride\`.

Attaching details logs for reference.

`pip install robotframework-ride`

Removed build tracker 'C:\Users\mani~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-vdskcs3j'
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mani~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ee73re19\robotframework-ride\
Exception information:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 141, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
        resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
        self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
        abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
        self.require_hashes
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 298, in prepare_linked_requirement
        abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 126, in prep_for_dist
        self.req.run_egg_info()
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 636, in run_egg_info
        command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 701, in call_subprocess
        % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
    pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mani~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ee73re19\robotframework-ride\
```

`easy_install robotframework-ride`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\mani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\easy_install.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 2312, in main
        **kw
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 412, in run
        self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 699, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 884, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1152, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1138, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\mani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\MPULAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-x0z_5joe\robotframework-ride-2.0a1\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue here as I can see simply from the **execfile not defined** is that the library that you are trying to install isn't supported on python3 yet. As python 3 or higher had modified that to **exec**. I looked at github and found some fixes.

You can look at this [thread](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/1719), user [helio](https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66) seems to have made a fork as the official project hasn't resolved the issue. So you can checkout his version and see if you can follow the instructions for his pre release for the concerned library.

**P.S. Kindly scroll down and check the pre-release first and then do the other workarounds that are mentioned in the initial comments**

Answer (score 0):

Try to install python 2.7.13 or newer version and use the 32 bit even if you have a laptop 64 bit : Windows x86 MSI installer

Answer (score 0):

There is a version compatible with Python's versions from 2.7. Unfortunately there are known bugs that can turn people away.
The releases are at https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/releases/.

Answer (score 0):

I installed robotframework-ride on **Windows 10 (1909 build)** successfully.

Please provide more details,

1. like what are the steps you have performed "before installing RF-RIDE"(is any), windows version, sometimes all these details seem to be ignored at first, it might make a difference at the time of debugging.
2. like what was the state of pip along with pip version etc whatever is relevant for others and yourself for the purposes of debugging.
3. Errors are seen while installing (like you have provided)

Try creating a virtualenv and continue installing RF-RIDE there and check if you are seeing any issue, and post your observations.

Also, Windows is atypical OS, so, also try with running cmd/whatever with "Admin privileges" and check(although i have not done that, since, am the admin)

Maybe, it would take us closer to a possible resolution.

**python 3.7.0**

```
(sof1) C:\Users\devfu>python -V
Python 3.7.0

(sof1) C:\Users\devfu>pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------------------
certifi      2019.9.11
pip          19.3.1
setuptools   41.6.0.post20191030
wheel        0.33.6
wincertstore 0.2

(sof1) C:\Users\devfu>pip install robotframework-ride
Collecting robotframework-ride
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/a6/1835a17fa566b19c166735a9a75d55101e53b68566771ddb0b690dd4be83/robotframework_ride-1.7.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\devfu\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\94\da\6e\2127e2253ef98b9b98b625e78f5158dd66966a5cc9f1d1478b\pypubsub-3.3.0-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/12/08d58ad0a782aa003f2f4c19c2d2d8a55bc0141f9b925ea2f066732a7319/wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting robotframeworklexer
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/18/ad01d42227d824b890f1b4d32237e5003bf7afe8764cb13545fb63d7fcb5/robotframeworklexer-1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pywin32
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/23/00fe4fbf9963f3bcb34a443eba0d0283fc51e5887d4045552c87490394e4/pywin32-227-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting Pygments
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/73/1dfa428150e3ccb0fa3e68db406e5be48698f2a979ccbcec795f28f44048/Pygments-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting robotframework
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/0f/1b9ffa0c4e59789b50e6034866e823b7d4a5c7eaedad7bfd0bba42f2aa9d/robotframework-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy; python_version >= "3.0"
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/40/c6eae19892551ff91bdb15f884fef2d42d6f58da55ab18fa540851b48a32/numpy-1.17.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/f4/9dd0b7b0fea09cf4e7a2822031f2157f40d41f0252a89558bdb583e24ef1/Pillow-6.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/26/32b8464df2a97e6dd1b656ed26b2c194606c16fe163c695a992b36c11cdf/six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: Pypubsub, numpy, pillow, six, wxPython, robotframeworklexer, Pywin32, Pygments, robotframework, robotframework-ride
Successfully installed Pygments-2.4.2 Pypubsub-3.3.0 Pywin32-227 numpy-1.17.4 pillow-6.2.1 robotframework-3.1.2 robotframework-ride-1.7.3.1 robotframeworklexer-1.1 six-1.13.0 wxPython-4.0.7.post2

(sof1) C:\Users\devfu>pip list
Package             Version
------------------- -------------------
certifi             2019.9.11
numpy               1.17.4
Pillow              6.2.1
pip                 19.3.1
Pygments            2.4.2
PyPubSub            3.3.0
pywin32             227
robotframework      3.1.2
robotframework-ride 1.7.3.1
robotframeworklexer 1.1
setuptools          41.6.0.post20191030
six                 1.13.0
wheel               0.33.6
wincertstore        0.2
wxPython            4.0.7.post2
```

**python3.7.5**

```
(sof0) C:\Users\devfu>python -V
Python 3.7.5

(sof0) C:\Users\devfu>pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------------------
certifi      2019.9.11
pip          19.3.1
setuptools   41.6.0.post20191030
wheel        0.33.6
wincertstore 0.2

(sof0) C:\Users\devfu>pip install robotframework-ride
Collecting robotframework-ride
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/a6/1835a17fa566b19c166735a9a75d55101e53b68566771ddb0b690dd4be83/robotframework_ride-1.7.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (926kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 931kB 1.6MB/s
Collecting Pygments
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/73/1dfa428150e3ccb0fa3e68db406e5be48698f2a979ccbcec795f28f44048/Pygments-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (883kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 890kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting robotframework
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/0f/1b9ffa0c4e59789b50e6034866e823b7d4a5c7eaedad7bfd0bba42f2aa9d/robotframework-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (602kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 604kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting wxPython
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/12/08d58ad0a782aa003f2f4c19c2d2d8a55bc0141f9b925ea2f066732a7319/wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (23.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 23.0MB 3.3MB/s
Collecting Pywin32
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/23/00fe4fbf9963f3bcb34a443eba0d0283fc51e5887d4045552c87490394e4/pywin32-227-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (9.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.1MB 3.3MB/s
Collecting robotframeworklexer
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/18/ad01d42227d824b890f1b4d32237e5003bf7afe8764cb13545fb63d7fcb5/robotframeworklexer-1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pypubsub==3.3.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/5a/1801be1a63af9250e79b8941a37b88e3ca0d660b880b9862fe9016ae6a3a/PyPubSub-3.3.0.zip (87kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 2.0MB/s
Collecting pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/f4/9dd0b7b0fea09cf4e7a2822031f2157f40d41f0252a89558bdb583e24ef1/Pillow-6.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 6.4MB/s
Collecting six
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/26/32b8464df2a97e6dd1b656ed26b2c194606c16fe163c695a992b36c11cdf/six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy; python_version >= "3.0"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/40/c6eae19892551ff91bdb15f884fef2d42d6f58da55ab18fa540851b48a32/numpy-1.17.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (12.7MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.7MB 6.4MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: Pypubsub
  Building wheel for Pypubsub (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for Pypubsub: filename=PyPubSub-3.3.0-cp37-none-any.whl size=80837 sha256=757b7fd0cd0aa4640948e76e28cca5c8e7147f45e253b1e6c7e398e72c10cbf0
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\devfu\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\94\da\6e\2127e2253ef98b9b98b625e78f5158dd66966a5cc9f1d1478b
Successfully built Pypubsub
Installing collected packages: Pygments, robotframework, pillow, six, numpy, wxPython, Pywin32, robotframeworklexer, Pypubsub, robotframework-ride
Successfully installed Pygments-2.4.2 Pypubsub-3.3.0 Pywin32-227 numpy-1.17.4 pillow-6.2.1 robotframework-3.1.2 robotframework-ride-1.7.3.1 robotframeworklexer-1.1 six-1.13.0 wxPython-4.0.7.post2

(sof0) C:\Users\devfu>pip list
Package             Version
------------------- -------------------
certifi             2019.9.11
numpy               1.17.4
Pillow              6.2.1
pip                 19.3.1
Pygments            2.4.2
PyPubSub            3.3.0
pywin32             227
robotframework      3.1.2
robotframework-ride 1.7.3.1
robotframeworklexer 1.1
setuptools          41.6.0.post20191030
six                 1.13.0
wheel               0.33.6
wincertstore        0.2
wxPython            4.0.7.post2
```